# Riemann Integration vs Lebesgue Integration

Tags: integration, measure-theory

If a function is not Riemann integrable, what does it mean geometrically?

Is it that we can't use integration to find out area under the curve? 
So basically when a function is Riemann integrable then it can tell us about area.

I am asking this because I saw a function which is not Riemann integrable but Lebesgue integrable.
What does it mean geometrically?

Comment: His name was Riemann! – [Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann)

Comment: Well, in fact his name was Georg Friedrich Bernhard. and Riemann was his family name.

Comment: a bounded function on a closed interval is Riemann integrable if it's continuous almost everywhere; the indicator function of the rational numbers on a closed interval is Lebesgue but not Riemann integrable

Comment: And please: use capital "R" ...It's the name of a great, great mathematician.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually non-Riemann integrable functions are pathological functions like the Dirichlet function etc. But these are Lebesgue integrable.

One of the main implications of a function being non-Riemann integrable is that it is not continuous enough to have a well-defined area under the curve. But the mathematical definition limits itself to the existence of a limiting sum only. In that sense, it is quite rigorous.

I further quote from this [article](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/2017/Wang.pdf):

> We realize that both of them can help us to integrate functions. The difference is that the Riemann integral subdivides the domain of a
>   function, while the Lebesgue integral subdivides the range of that function. The
>   step function for Riemann integral has a constant value in each of the subintervals of the partition, while the simple function for Lebesgue integral provides
>   finitely many measurable sets corresponding to each value of that function.
>   The improvement from the Riemann integral to the Lebesgue integral is that
>   the Lebesgue integral provides more generality than the Riemann integral does.
>   From the reverse perspective, the Riemann integral can imply the Lebesgue
>   integral.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, as soon as you start with the Lebesgue integral, it is hard to find geometric interpretations that hold in every case.
The comment by @J.W. Tanner is the one that gets closest in my opinion. He states the Lebesgue criteria for Riemann integrable functions:

A function is Riemann integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere.

Geometrically you can imagine drawing the graph of a function $f$ on an interval and you only jump countably many times. Be careful and note that, for example, the function $g(x) = 1$, if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is not Riemann integrable, even though $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. That is because $g$ is continuous nowhere.

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful